# How can I put user input into an int value in C#?

Tags: c#

How can I put my user input to an integer value, and throw an error if the input is text?
I also want them to be int values, so that I can do mathematical operations on them.

Here is my code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please type number 1.");
int num1 = Console.Read();
Console.WriteLine(num1);
Console.WriteLine("Please type number 2.");
int num2 = Console.Read();
Console.WriteLine(num2);
```

Here is what it outputs(italicized text is user's input)

```
> Please type number 1.
> *1* 
> 49
> Please type number 2. 
> 13
```

Comment: int.Parse or int.TryParse

Comment: instead of Console.Read use Console.ReadLine - Read only reads the first character, therefor you couldn’t enter `123` as it would be 3 different inputs `1` and `2` and `3`

Answer (score 2):

`Console.Read()` reads one characters that you have typed and returns the character value as an integer.

You've typed `1<enter>2<enter>` so those characters are `49, 13, 10, 50, 13, 10`. Which is why your calls to `Console.Read()` returned `49` and then `13`.

If you want to read the actual numbers you're typing as text, you need to do something like this:

```
int ReadInt32()
{
    int value = 0;
    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out value))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
    }
    return value;
}
```

Now that enables your code with minimal changes:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please type number 1.");
int num1 = ReadInt32();
Console.WriteLine(num1);
Console.WriteLine("Please type number 2.");
int num2 = ReadInt32();
Console.WriteLine(num2);
```

When executed it behaves as you're expecting.

Answer (score -1):

when you do `Console.ReadLine()`, it always returns a `string`. You can put the result in an `int` by parsing the string. For example:

```
string text = Console.ReadLine();
int number = int.Parse(text);
```

Make sure that the string you're parsing is actually a number, or you're get an error.

If you insist on using `Console.Read()`, know that `Console.Read()` reads one character at a time. Here are the steps to parse that:

```
int code = Console.Read();
char character = (char)code;
string str = character.ToString();
int number = int.Parse(str);
Console.WriteLine(number);
```

You can add a check to make sure that the character that has been read in is a number like so:

```
int code = Console.Read();
char character = (char)code;
if(character >= '0' && character <= '9')
{
    string str = character.ToString();
    int number = int.Parse(str);
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not a number: '" + character + "'");
}
```

Comment: @RandRandom whoops, meant ReadLine().

Comment: The OP isn't using `ReadLine`. You might want to word your answer so that it addresses what the OP is actually doing.

Comment: I used a different way.